# Does the local GIT Branch and remote GITHUB branch need to be the same to push the code?

Tags: git, github

I created a new local Branch and trying to push the code to a new remote branch. When the local and remote branch names differ, the code isn't getting pushed. But when the names are same, code is getting pushed. Is this behavior normal or am I missing anything? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a basic complete push command, it's like

```
git push <remote> <local_revision>:<remote_ref>
```

`<local_revision>:<remote_ref>` is a [refspec](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt-ltrefspecgt82308203).

For example, to push the 2nd parent of the commit `abc123` to create a new ref `refs/sandbox/foo`,

```
git push origin abc123^2:refs/sandbox/foo
```

To push the local `master` to the remote (`origin` in this case) `master`,

```
git push origin refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
```

When `master` is indeed a branch, we can omit the `refs/heads/` part if no naming conflicts,

```
git push origin master:master
```

When the local branch and the target branch are both named `master`, we can omit the target branch name,

```
git push origin master
```

With the help of some configuration variables, we can shorten the command further. When the current branch is `master` and in git config `branch.master.remote=origin` and `remote.origin.push=refs/heads/*:refs/heads/*` are set, we can simply run `git push`.